# Set different filename and Task Bar name when build app using electron-packager

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-scripts, electron-packager

I have an application which use electron packager for build app on Mac.

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "desktop_v2"
    "productName": "desktop v2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
      "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e",
      "package:osx": "npm run build-prod & cross-var electron-packager $npm_package_name-$npm_package_version  dist --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite"
    },
    "build": {
        "category": "your.app.category.type",
        "productName": "desktop v2",
    }
    ...
}
```

when I run

```
npm run package:osx
```

It work, however an app file name is  **desktop_v2-1.0.0.app** has the same with the App title on 
 taskbar **desktop_v2-1.0.0** (`$npm_package_name-$npm_package_version` ). And I do not like to see the version on taskbar. So, how can I set .app name different with the app title name?

ex: **file name**: desktop_v2-1.0.0.app

**App Title**: desktop v2

Comment: Does replacing the `$npm_package_name-$npm_package_version` part in `package:osx` script with `\"$npm_package_build_productName\"` meet your requirement? Or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: No, My code work, but after it execute i get a file which has the same name with app title (here is: **desktop_v2-1.0.0** from $npm_package_name-$npm_package_version). I just want productName set for App Title and desktop_v2-1.0.0 set for file name (don't have to rename that file manual ) . Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": {
      "package:osx": "npm run build-prod & cross-var electron-packager Hello-World  dist --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite"
    },
```

file name will be : Hello-World.app

Comment: Yes you are right, It will set filename Hello-World.app and also set Application Title Hello-World. How can I tell the script get productName for Application Title?

Comment: @DatLieu $npm_package_productName or $npm_package_build_productName

Comment: @DatLieu "package:osx": "npm run build-prod & cross-var electron-packager $npm_package_productName  dist --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite"

Comment: Sr, I just ask the author of electron-packager, and they do not support for set filename different with App title. So, I have to move on electron-builder

Comment: @alex dynkyi  "npm run build-prod & cross-var electron-packager $npm_package_name-$npm_package_version  dist --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite" will set App Title = desktop_v2-1.0.0

Comment: @DatLieu Just use this
"package:osx": "npm run build-prod & cross-var electron-packager $npm_package_productName dist --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite"

Comment: Yes, In case we use electron-pakager  "package:osx": "npm run build-prod & cross-var electron-packager $npm_package_productName dist --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite" is the best script. However I found that electron-builder build zip file has version in file name which solve my case :))